# ¿Condicionar un formulario en symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony2

Pues tengo el siguiente dato en un formulario de symfony:

```
->add('lugar', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Lugar',
                'mapped' => false,
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('e')
                        ->orderBy('e.horaInicio', 'ASC');
                },
                'choice_label' => 'lugar',
                'label' => 'Desea acudir a las siguientes horas? (15:45-17:00)'
            ))
```

Actualmente este código me muestra todas las horas que hay en `horaInicio`, me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de coger sólo las que muestro en el código, con un `if` o algún método por el estilo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya que usas el parámetro `query_builder`, puedes usarlo para filtrar los elementos que se van a mostrar:

```
'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
     return $er->createQueryBuilder('e')
               ->where(/* tu condición aquí */)
               ->orderBy('e.horaInicio', 'ASC');
},
```

Por ejemplo, para usar un rango de fechas:

```
'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
     return $er->createQueryBuilder('e')
               ->where('e.date > :datetimeStart') // Campo fecha es mayor que...
               ->andWhere('e.date < :datetimeEnd') // Campo fecha es menor que...
               ->setParameter('datetimeStart', new \DateTime('now')) // mayor que hoy
               ->setParameter('datetimeEnd', new \DateTime('tomorrow')) // menor que mañana
               ->orderBy('e.horaInicio', 'ASC');
},
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta antes de nada, y se podría coger un intervalo de fechas? Como estoy usando un datetime que marca la hora de inicio y la hora de fin, si se podrian mostrar solo los datos que esten dentro de el intervalo

Comment: Desconozco tu caso específico, pero te he actualizado con un ejemplo para que tengas una idea de como limitar la consulta en un intervalo. Obviamente tendrás que modificar el código para adaptarlo a tus necesidades.

Comment: Muchas gracias, el código ya está preparado para tal dado que son fechas y solo quiero compararlas en el formulario

Answer (score 1):

Otra forma que podeis usar (basada en la de Muriano) es pasarle al querybuilder parametros definidos antes del formulario. por ej:

```
'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($start, $end) {
     return $er->createQueryBuilder('e')
    ->where('e.date > :datetimeStart')
    ->andWhere('e.date < :datetimeEnd')
    ->setParameter('datetimeStart', $start)
    ->setParameter('datetimeEnd', $end) // menor que mañana
    ->orderBy('e.horaInicio', 'ASC');
},
```

$start y $end hay que definirlos antes de llamar al add del campo que estes definiendo.

Comment: y los defino en el propio formulario o donde?

Comment: antes del formulario. el use se utiliza para utilizar los parametros dentro de las funciones anonimas, como por ejemplo la que utilizas con el query_builder.

Comment: no estoy muy seguro de donde debería definirlo, siento mi ignorancia pero acabo de entrar en el mundo de symfony y es todo nuevo para mi

Comment: yo utilizo dos formas de hacer los formularios. Una con la entidad (en el controlador, algo como **$form = $this->createForm(FormType::class, $entity);**) y otra con el **createFormBuilder()->add**...  Si utilizas la primera forma, tendras que editar tu entidad FormType; si utilizas la segunda, debes definir esas variables antes del createFormBuilder()

Comment: Yo tengo los formularios aparte en la carpeta form, asi que supongo que deberia definirlos antes del `buildform`?

Comment: Eso es. Ahora bien, si pretendes que el controlador cree esos parametros, tendras que pasarselos luego a la entidad form en el tercer parametro de createForm(class, object, array). En ese array se pasarian los datos al **configureOptions** de la clase form.

Comment: No, los parametros, es decir los datos que necesito estan en la base de datos ( las horas ) lo único que necesito es hacer que solo salgan ciertas horas, pero no consigo hacerlo por mucho que indague y no entiendo muy bien como definirlo

Comment: Fallo mio, gracias por tu ayuda, estaba llamando a la clase que no era, menudo fallo de principiante